# PHP CLI - STDIN -or- Reload script

Tags: php, linux, command-line-interface

I'm looking to write a small PHP CLI application on a Linux OS that displays a few values from a MySQL database table so that I can SSH in when I'm not inside the network (SSH is the only port opened up to the outside, so CLI is the only option).

I'd also like it to both a) receive input from STDIN to choose between two different screens, as well as refresh the page every 30 seconds (even if it calls itself after a sleep() command).

So far I've only been able to do one or the other and not both. A bit tricky as it won't refresh until it's received input.

If someone's got an idea, on how to do this, it'd be great.

**What I have so far for the self-refresh:**

```
sleep(30);
system("./filename.php");
```

**The following is what I have so far for the STDIN input:**

```
do {
  $choice = trim(fgets(STDIN));
} while(!(($choice == "1") || ($choice == "2") || ($choice == "q")));


switch($choice) {
    case "1":
        loadScreen1();
    case "2":
        loadScreen2();
    case "q":
        exit();
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the means you should look at [ncurses](http://php.net/ncurses) PHP extension for full terminal control without having to rely on `system` calls.

Comment: The only system calls that are done are to load a different CLI script or clear the screen. Is ncurses able to do what I require? If so, can you provide examples please?

Comment: To clear the screen you would use `ncurses_clear` function. Is there a reason why you need multiple CLI scripts? You could implement all screens within a single PHP script.

Comment: We're getting off topic here. My question is: is there a way allow me to enter input to STDIN of a PHP CLI script while also reloading the script every 30sec even while no input? Can ncurses do that? I can consolidate and learn ncurses later. I'd like a solution for now.